# Is it possible to force a model to completely load in WebGL?

Tags: webgl

I'm loading a bunch of obj models, that are reasonably heavy, 120 odd textures each. They load fine and eventually render, but as they are drawn for the first time, the frame rate drops through the floor and the materials of objects appear black until the textures are loaded.

Is there a way to ensure the models and their textures are fully loaded before displaying them, or at least query if they're ready to be drawn?
Also, is there a way to encourage the textures to load? It seems like they don't load until the object is drawn.

Thanks

Comment: WebGL doesn't know anything at all about models so it's difficult to say what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = [/*..image list...*/];
var loaded = [];
var numReady = 0;

for(var i= images.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    loaded[i] = new Image();
    loaded[i].src = images[i];
    loaded[i].onload = function() {
        numReady++;
    };
}

// in render loop
if(numReady==images.length) {
    //now ready to render
}
```

Basically, just check how many textures have loaded at each frame, and when they finally load you're ready to do drawing.

Comment: The loader I'm using, is the OBJMTLLoader, which in turn uses the MTLLoader to load a material and the textures that are referenced. There are several levels of loads with callbacks and it looks like there's nothing to track the number of textures as you've described.
I'll look into adding code to manage that. 
Thanks

Comment: Well, whichever loader, it has some callback from `onload` of the Image object, so that needs to be located and somehow included in check if all textures are ready or not. This answer shows the general principle. Good luck. :)

Comment: So I've found some time to look into this a bit more.

Comment: I found the following thread that suggests that the monitoring of loading textures has had some love recently:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1751

Sure enough, after all of the textures are _loaded_ by the MTLLoader, there are only a couple of textures on the GPU. Then when I move my objects on screen, they are all added. 


I looked into the MTLLoader code and it turns out that all of the textures are in fact loaded into memory fairly quickly.

I then used Ben Vaniks WebGL inspector to check when textures are loaded on the GPU. 
http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/

Comment: I'm happy to get my hands dirty in the rendering code of Threejs, so if anyone can give me a starting point for where the textures are sent to the GPU that would be great. 

Thanks again.

Comment: Textures are loaded but not immediately prepared for rendering. If there is some mesh that uses certain texture that only has image loaded but hasn't been prepared for rendering (by that I mean converted to WebGLTexture type) then the renderer would prepare it and than send that uniform to shader. Search for the part of the renderer that sends uniforms to shader.